# Loading/unloading specific modules in jboss-7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I want my jboss-7 to be configured in such a way that it will not load some specified modules while starting up. Is this achievable? If so, what should I do to achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Modules can load only the classes you need and does so with extremely fast, O(1) resolution. In addition, classes can be loaded concurrently, making use of that multi-core processor once again.

[Class Loading and Modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html)